# Generating 50k rows of unix time entries auto-incremented 5 mintes each

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I am relatively new at using mysql, or any DB for that matter, so let me know if I'm doing this in a round-about way.

I have 4 similar tables with two <del>rows</del> columns each - unixtime + count. They all look something like this:

```
mysql> select * from wifiexporttotal limit 5;
+------------+-------+
| epoch      | count |
+------------+-------+
| 1446292800 |   298 |
| 1446293100 |   332 |
| 1446293400 |   375 |
| 1446293700 |   439 |
| 1446294000 |   412 |
+------------+-------+
```

etc...

These are log entries rounded to the nearest 5 minute interval for approx 6 months with around 50k entries each.

I want to join these in a single table with unixtime + 4 columns of values, and have done so successfully. However, there are some timestamps without a log entry in any of the four tables, and I would like for these to show zero instead of <del>missing</del> skipping rows.

So my question is - How can I generate a table with 50k rows and a single column that starts with a bigint (1446332400 for nov 1st in my case) and auto increments with 300 (5 minutes) per row? I assume I could LEFT JOIN the other 4 tables with this table on the timestamp and get an unbroken string of 5 minute intervals for the 6 months this way.

Comment: You can use the trick used in http://stackoverflow.com/a/16317952 and just generate timestamps instead of dates.

Comment: That gets me part of the way - I can get a date range that I can convert to UNIX_TIMESTAMP, but I'm looking for 300 second intervals - not 24 hour intervals. - It is neat though, and I can actually use it elsewhere.

Comment: The main part is a number serie generator, you can just remove the dates altogether and add multiples of 300s to the starting timestamp.

Comment: Terminology:  `epoch` and `count` are "columns".  Your sample data has 5 "rows".

Comment: Thanks about the terminology - I don't know why I mixed those two up - I'm pretty used to the terms from spreadsheets! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plan A:  (Drawback: you might still have gaps.)

1. Find all `epoch` values from the 4 tables using `UNION DISTINCT`.
2. `LEFT JOIN` from that table to the other 4 tables.

Plan B:  (Drawback: I don't say how to do step 1.)

1. Build a `TEMPORARY` table with every 5-min time for the next N months.
2. `LEFT JOIN` ...

Plan C:  (Drawback: Step 1.)

1. Upgrade to MariaDB.
2. Use a "sequence" table to 'virtually' generate enough integers.
3. Use some simple arithmetic to convert the integers to epochs.
4. `LEFT JOIN` ...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I ended up trying Plan B with success! - I generated a 100k row table with 1446332400 as the first value and used a for loop to generate the rows with 300 increments. I then exported the table to a file for re-use.